# Count past relative number of rows that meet criteria similar to excel's COUNTIF

Tags: pandas

I have a stock data csv with the following info

```
   Open    High    Low      Close
0  154.55  155.54  152.90   153.41
1  156.82  158.75  155.42   156.76
2  150.21  157.44  150.15   156.33
3  147.78  149.38  146.88   149.11
4  144.25  147.28  143.90   146.27
5  142.90  144.05  140.79   143.73
>>>
```

I want to count how many of the previous two highs were above the current open.
In excel I can do this [image: Excel spreadsheet image]

I would like to calculate this using pandas, but so far I have not been able to get anything working.
The closest I have gotten is with the following function and then using apply

```
def high_counter(day_open):
    count = 0
    for i in data['High'][:+2]:
        if i > day_open:
            count += 1
    return count
```

```
data['Number of previous highs above'] = data['Open'].apply(high_counter)
```

However, this leads to the comparison always starting from the top down instead of down from the relative cell like in excel.

To summarize, I need to compare the Open with the previous N highs and get a count of how many are above the relative open whether that Open is the first row or the 50th row. The Highs to be compared would begin at the row prior the Open and would be of N size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df["above"] = pd.DataFrame([df["High"].shift(-1)>df["Open"],
                            df["High"].shift(-2)>df["Open"]]).T.sum(axis=1)

# or [df["High"].shift(n)>df["Open"] for n in range(-1,-5,-1)] if you want to generalize the number n

print (df)

     Open    High     Low   Close  above
0  154.55  155.54  152.90  153.41      2
1  156.82  158.75  155.42  156.76      1
2  150.21  157.44  150.15  156.33      0
3  147.78  149.38  146.88  149.11      0
4  144.25  147.28  143.90  146.27      0
5  142.90  144.05  140.79  143.73      0
```

Comment: I get a "Value Error: Length of values does not match length of index" When trying the second example.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([df["High"].shift(n)>df["Open"] for n in range(-1,-5,-1)]).T.sum(axis=1)` is what i meant.